# Fetch value/values from table

Tags: mysql, sql, function, procedure

I have the following table in my database

```
CREATE TABLE `sms_pool` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ag_id` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `sms_to` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `template_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `contents` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    `bulk_flag` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `file_name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `send_flag` VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `creation_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `created_by` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `processing_msg` VARCHAR(2000) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),    
);
```

I wish to write a procedure/function which takes 'id' as input.

If that 'id' is equal to any id in table then it should return the corresponding row,

if 'id' = NULL then it should return all of the rows from the database.

**NOTE** : if 'id' is not present in table then it should return all of the rows.

How should I do this? Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance. :D

Comment: what you have tried so far .....let us know

Comment: Instead of a procedure, why not just write some application code that runs one of two different queries? Stored procedures are often nothing but trouble due to how they can't be manipulated without changing global behaviour.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal I have handled the above requirement in application code, but I wanted to know if it's possible to handle it in sql query or not. By the way thank you for your answer.

Comment: @abhi314 i have made few changes in my code ..have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure sp_get_data(in in_id int)
begin
      declare temp_id int;
      set temp_id =(select count(*) from table_name where id =in_id);
      if(temp_id) >0
      Then 
          select * from table_name where id = in_id ;              
      else 
          select * from table_name ;
      end 
end
```

Comment: why downvote ?? please specify